# Error when submitting an app in TestFlight (iTunes Connect) for External Testers

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm trying to submit an app for External Testers in iTunes Connect (TestFlight) and I got this message :

> Invalid sdk value. The value provided for the sdk portion of
>   LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS in ***APP_NAME*** is 9.2 which is
>   greater than the maximum allowed value of 9.1.

I built this app with the latest XCode 7.2 (iOS 9.2) released today, with a Deployment Target of iOS 8.0, Base SDK "Latest iOS (iOS 9.2)".

Is it because this is a new version and we can't submit apps built with XCode 7.2 yet?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Same here trying to submit to the iOS App Store. I figure Apple has forgotten to flip some switch after dropping XCode 7.2/OSX 10.11.2/iOS 9.2 today. Hopefully it'll be resolved soon.

Comment: I've got the same problem and I really hope it'll be solved because I have some critical bugs I have to clear off

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I met the same problems, maybe it is because apple release iOS9.2 today, so it may take some time to update itunes connect backend;

For more details check here [Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/27912)

`Give the backend 24 hrs. to catch up, then try again.`

Update:

If you need submit urgently, try to download an old version of Xcode [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) and rebuild a new binary. Do not forget to update your build number.

Update2:

**You can submit it again. It works now.**

Answer (score 3):

I have same problems for all frameworks I use. Try older version of Xcode.
Version 7.1 should work.

**UPDATE: 
Itunesconnect already works. I have successfully uploaded new build for external testing**

Answer (score 2):

This error is already gone - you can now submit the apps with Xcode 7.2 :)

Comment: It works! Hooray for SO, my most responsive proxy-bug reporter ever ;)